# How to get the right output from this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im creating a sql query that outputs the licensePlate from dbo.car when there is any stock of the car. Which means i will have to look under dbo.Sell and dbo.Rent to make sure that a car is not sold or under rental.

I need to have a output with the following:

```
LicensePlateNo
--------------
SGK5556A
```

But the output will always be blank.
I have the following statement:

```
SELECT 
    LicensePlateNo 
FROM car 
INNER JOIN CarTransaction ON     
    car.ChassisNo =  CarTransaction.ChassisNo 
INNER JOIN Sell on 
    CarTransaction.TransactionID = Sell.TransactionID
INNER JOIN Rent on 
    CarTransaction.TransactionID = Rent.TransactionID
WHERE  
    Car.Make = 'Toyota' AND 
    Sell.TransactionID IN (SELECT TransactionID FROM Sell) AND
    Rent.TransactionID IN (SELECT TransactionID FROM Rent)
```

I cant seem to get the right query. The only moment when the query works is when i did not specify the query for dbo.Rent. But i need to validate whether if the car is available through the rental history

Comment: The car is never in Sell AND in Rent, so I think all you need to do is put a NOT in front of your two IN.

Comment: Do you use MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Hi Glorfindel, my bad for using wrong tag. Im using MS sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner joins are not needed and the car is never in sell and rent at the same time, query can be written as:

```
SELECT
  LicensePlateNo
FROM
  Car
  INNER JOIN
    CarTransaction 
  ON 
    Car.ChassisNo = CarTransaction.ChassisNo
WHERE
  Car.Make = 'Toyota' AND
  CarTransaction.TransactionID NOT IN (SELECT TransactionID FROM Sell) AND
  CarTransaction.TransactionID NOT IN (SELECT TransactionID FROM Rent)
;
```

Comment: Thank you! it gives me the expected result! Thumbs up!

Comment: You are welcome, I just see that if you switch the first left join to an inner join in Glorfindel's response, then it will be the same. Regarding performance I'm not sure which is better, best to measure in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

This query will only produce results if you have a car that has been sold **and** has been under rental. That is what INNER JOINs are for - they only give results when a record is found in both tables.

I guess you want a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT LicensePlateNo FROM car
  LEFT JOIN CarTransaction ON car.ChassisNo = CarTransaction.ChassisNo 
  LEFT JOIN Sell ON CarTransaction.TransactionID = Sell.TransactionID
  LEFT JOIN Rent ON CarTransaction.TransactionID = Rent.TransactionID
  WHERE Car.Make = 'Toyota'
    AND Sell.TransactionID IS NULL
    AND Rent.TransactionID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks for the explanation :)